# "Poor" quality when zooming out WMS-Layer based on GeoTiff data

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

I am having some issues when using the GeoServer Web Mapping Service to display GeoTIFF-Files. When zooming out (in an OpenLayers-Client or in the GeoServer Layer Preview for instance) the quality seems to be very poor. When opening the GeoTIFF in a picture viewer the quality seems to be ok

[image: screen shot]

I am working on a project where i have to display very old maps in an webbased application, so the quality is quite important.
I have alredy tried to alter the compression levels of the wms in GeoServer, in vain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add overviews to your image using gdaladdo, using -r average. Your viewer is probably building an image pyramid in memory or on disk, creating the same effect as persistent overviews.

Answer (score 5):

Your picture viewer uses a different resampling method. In GeoServer you can change the default interpolation from the default nearest neighbor interpolation to bilinear or bicubic:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/services/WMS.html

Be aware that bilinear and bicubic interpolations require more resources.